# Java: How to print the next line of found string

Tags: java, input

This code works and it prints the line but I would like it to print the next line.

```
import java.io.*;

public class SearchTextFile {
    //
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        int tokencount;
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("c:\\searchtxt.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String s;
        int linecount = 0;

        String keyword = "something";
        String line;

        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (s.contains(keyword))
                System.out.println(s);

        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: So ... read the next line and print it!  What is the actual problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify this part of your code:

```
while ((s=br.readLine())!=null) {
  if(s.contains(keyword))
      System.out.println(s);
}
```

Here you're printing the line that contains the keyword. Since you want to print the next line, use the `BufferedReader` to read the next line again inside the `if` condition. Therefore, it would be something like this:

```
while ((s=br.readLine())!=null) {
    if(s.contains(keyword)) {
        //System.out.println(s);
        String nextLine = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(nextLine);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    boolean isFound = false;
    String line = null;


    while (line = br.readline() != null){
        if(isFound){
            System.out.print(line)
            isFound = false;
        }

        if(line.contains(keyword)){
            isFound = true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: An explanation of how your code works and what it does would be nice.

Comment: The difference between my code and the code submitted by Anindya Dutta is that when you execute br.readLine() you advance the curser reading through the file. So by printing the next line in the same if block you are checking for the keyword you lose the opportunity to check the next line for the keyword as well.  

My code will read the line and check to see if it contains the keyword. If it does it sets a boolean that will be used to print the next line After printing the next line it then checks that same line for the keyword as well.

Comment: My code will check every line for the keyword and the "selected" answer will not check the line after lines that contain the keyword.

Answer (score 0):

To print the line after `keyword` is found I'd do something simple like this:

```
boolean foundString = false;
while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (s.contains(keyword)) {
        System.out.println(s);
        foundString = true;
    } else if (foundString) {
        System.out.println(s);
        foundString = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(s.contains(keyword))
  System.out.println(br.readline());
```